# force c++ program to show 'synchronized' output to MATLAB command window using dos()

Tags: matlab, command-window

I'm executing my c++ compiled program in MATLAB with `dos('myprog.exe')`. myprog produces some output that it is printed to the MATLAB command window only after myprog.exe finishes execution.

Is there a way to force MATLAB print the output when it is produced by myprog.exe and not at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANSWER**
Make sure that you are flushing correctly the output buffers in your c++ program. In my experience it sometimes helps to insert additional flushing commands (not just end of lines commands) to your code:

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

**NOTE**
You might also try to call your program like this:

```
[status,result] = dos('myprog.exe','-echo') 
[status,result] = system('myprog.exe','-echo')
```

The matlab help says: *"'echo' forces the output to the Command Window, even though it is also being assigned into a variable."*

However this might not work because (again matlab help):
*"Console programs never execute in the background. Also, the MATLAB software always waits for the stdout pipe to close before continuing execution. "* This means, that matlab might wait until your program finishes its execution before it shows you the console output. In that case there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: This doesn't work, but there has to be a way. Why does `msbuild` output show OK?

Comment: then try to add additional statements that flush the output buffers in your 'myprog.exe'

Comment: You can also try: [status,result] = system('myprog.ext','-echo') or !myprog.exe

Comment: the first one already tried, the second doesn't work. Take a look at the question again, I edited it. It might ring a bell

Comment: @memmyself: you were right it was a problem of correct flushing. Replacing some newlines with `std::endl` (which is also a flusher) it finally worked. I might have gotten something wrong when tested the first time. Modify your answer so I can accept it.